# Validate methods execute in parallel

Tags: scala, mockito, scalatest

I am creating a unit test to show that two methods execute in parallel. To this I mock the two methods and have them both have a delay of 2 seconds. I then validate the unit test took less than 4 (so I can be sure the actions are not executed sequentially because then it would take more than 4 [2*2] seconds).

Is there a better way?

Comment: Log start and end in the mock. Both should start before either end, and you can use the log entries to check this (or increment a shared variable - atomically! - when the task starts, decrement when it ends, keep track of its max, and check the answer is two). Etc.

Comment: Are the two methods from the same mock?

Comment: @LorenzoMurrocu we would like to support both situations. Same mock and different one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the InOrder feature.
This is an example for the case the two methods are from the same mock:

```
@Test
public void foo() {
    MyClass mock = Mockito.mock(MyClass.class);
    Mockito.when(mock.methodOne())thenAnswer(new Answer<ReturnType>()
    {

        @Override
        public ReturnType answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable
        {
            // Implement the delay or parallel execution
            . . . 
            mock.methodThree(); // This invocation is just a hook to intercept the end of this method execution
            return something;
        }
    });

    Mockito.when(mock.methodTwo())thenAnswer(new Answer<ReturnType>()
    {

        @Override
        public ReturnType answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable
        {
            // Implement the delay or the parallel execution
            . . .
            mock.methodThree(); // This invocation is just a hook to intercept the end of this method execution
            return something;
        }
    });



    // Here there should be the call to the real method that calls the two methods in parallel: 
    // !!HERE!!
    // mock1.methodOne();
    // mock2.methodTwo();

    InOrder inOrder = Mockito.inOrder(mock1, mock2);
    inOrder.verify(mock1).methodOne(); //asserts that methodOne should be invoked first
    inOrder.verify(mock2).methodTwo(); //asserts that methodTwo should be invoked after methodOne
    inOrder.verify(mock3, Mockito.calls(2)).methodThree(); //asserts that methodThree, that is invoked at the end of methodOne, is invoked after the methodTwo invocation.  These asserts together tell us that methodTwo was called during the execution of methodOne.
}
```

You can use the InOrder also with multiple mocks:

```
@Test
public void foo() {
    MyClass mock1 = Mockito.mock(MyClass.class);
    MyClass mock2 = Mockito.mock(MyClass.class);
    OtherClass mock3 = Mockito.mock(OtherClass.class);

    Mockito.when(mock1.methodOne())thenAnswer(new Answer<ReturnType>()
    {

        @Override
        public ReturnType answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable
        {
            // Implement the delay or the parallel execution
            . . .
            mock3.methodThree(); // This invocation is just a hook to intercept the end of this method execution
            return something;
        }
    });

    Mockito.when(mock2.methodTwo())thenAnswer(new Answer<ReturnType>()
    {

        @Override
        public ReturnType answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable
        {
            // Implement the delay or the parallel execution 
            . . .
            mock3.methodThree(); // This invocation is just a hook to intercept the end of this method execution
            return something;
        }
    });


    // Here there should be the call to the real method that calls the two methods in parallel: 
    // !!HERE!!
    // mock1.methodOne();
    // mock2.methodTwo();

    InOrder inOrder = Mockito.inOrder(mock1, mock2);
    inOrder.verify(mock1).methodOne(); //asserts that methodOne should be invoked first
    inOrder.verify(mock2).methodTwo(); //asserts that methodTwo should be invoked after methodOne
    inOrder.verify(mock3, Mockito.calls(2)).methodThree(); //asserts that methodThree, that is invoked at the end of methodOne, is invoked after the methodTwo invocation. These asserts together tell us that methodTwo was called during the execution of methodOne.
}
```

In this example, mock3 is just an instance whose only purpose is to hook the end of the execution of the two methods, so it should be mocked with a `doNothing`. Maybe in your scenario this can be achieved differently.

EDIT:
I will now explain better my answer: in the example I shared, there are only mocks, so the test is useless. In the code, where I added `!!HERE!!`, there should be the call to the real method that actually calls the two mocked methods in parallel. Alternatively, the two instances of `Answer` should be implemented to execute in parallel, but a test with only mocks is not useful..
Given that, the inOrder configured as I did in my example, verifies that the second invocation occurs before the end of the first one (look at the comments I added).

More information about InOrder interface:
http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/InOrder.html
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mockito/mockito_ordered_verification.htm

Comment: Thank you. I do not understand how this validates that methodOne and methodTwo execute in parallel. Can you explain that?